# Alfresco 4.0.d - Remote (External) Authentication with Share

Tags: authentication, alfresco, alfresco-share

I am trying to configure alfresco with remote authentication using apache (shibboleth module) in front of Alfresco - essentially passing REMOTE_USER from apache to alfresco after authenticating. I am able to configure alfresco where I can successfully log into /alfresco (classic explorer gui), however, /share (newer gui) does not log me in. Has anyone experienced/solved this issue?

Here is some details:

1. setup apache with the shibboleth mod (which works since i get automatcially logged into /alfresco)
2. setup ajp entry for both /alfresco and /share in apache.

   #### Alfresco Explorer

   ProxyPass /alfresco ajp://127.0.0.1:8009/alfresco

   ProxyPassReverse /alfresco ajp://127.0.0.1:8009/alfresco

   #### Alfresco Share

   ProxyPass /share ajp://127.0.0.1:8009/share

   ProxyPassReverse /share ajp://127.0.0.1:8009/share
3. setup tomcat ajp entry
4. set /tomcat/shared/classes/alfresco-global.properties with

   authentication.chain=external1:external,alfrescoNtlm1:alfrescoNtlm
   external.authentication.proxyUserName=
   external.authentication.proxyHeader=
   external.authentication.enabled=true
5. in share-config-custom.xml, i have put in the suggested xml entries below:

> Blockquote

```
<alfresco-config>

<!-- Repository Library config section -->
<config evaluator="string-compare" condition="RepositoryLibrary" replace="true">
<!--
Whether the link to the Repository Library appears in the header component or not.
-->
<visible>true</visible>
</config>

<config evaluator="string-compare" condition="Remote">
<remote>
<endpoint>
<id>alfresco-noauth</id>
<name>Alfresco - unauthenticated access</name>
<description>Access to Alfresco Repository WebScripts that do not require authentication</description>
<connector-id>alfresco</connector-id>
<endpoint-url>http://localhost:8080/alfresco/s</endpoint-url>
<identity>none</identity>
</endpoint>

<endpoint>
<id>alfresco</id>
<name>Alfresco - user access</name>
<description>Access to Alfresco Repository WebScripts that require user authentication</description>
<connector-id>alfresco</connector-id>
<endpoint-url>http://localhost:8080/alfresco/s</endpoint-url>
<identity>user</identity>
</endpoint>

<endpoint>
<id>alfresco-feed</id>
<name>Alfresco Feed</name>
<description>Alfresco Feed - supports basic HTTP authentication via the EndPointProxyServlet</description>
<connector-id>http</connector-id>
<endpoint-url>http://localhost:8080/alfresco/s</endpoint-url>
<basic-auth>true</basic-auth>
<identity>user</identity>
</endpoint>

<endpoint>
<id>activiti-admin</id>
<name>Activiti Admin UI - user access</name>
<description>Access to Activiti Admin UI, that requires user authentication</description>
<connector-id>activiti-admin-connector</connector-id>
<endpoint-url>http://localhost:8080/alfresco/activiti-admin</endpoint-url>
<identity>user</identity>
</endpoint>
</remote>
</config>

<config evaluator="string-compare" condition="Remote">
<remote>
<keystore>
<path>alfresco/web-extension/alfresco-system.p12</path>
<type>pkcs12</type>
<password>alfresco-system</password>
</keystore>

<connector>
<id>alfrescoCookie</id>
<name>Alfresco Connector</name>
<description>Connects to an Alfresco instance using cookie-based authentication</description>
<class>org.alfresco.web.site.servlet.SlingshotAlfrescoConnector</class>
</connector>

<endpoint>
<id>alfresco</id>
<name>Alfresco - user access</name>
<description>Access to Alfresco Repository WebScripts that require user authentication</description>
<connector-id>alfrescoCookie</connector-id>
<endpoint-url>http://localhost:8080/alfresco/wcs</endpoint-url>
<identity>user</identity>
<external-auth>true</external-auth>
</endpoint>
</remote>
</config>
```

> Blockquote

Answer (score 0):

Try defining a connector called 'alfrescoHeader':

```
     <connector>
        <id>alfrescoHeader</id>
        <name>Alfresco Connector</name>
        <description>Connects to an Alfresco instance using header and cookie-based authentication</description>
        <class>org.alfresco.web.site.servlet.SlingshotAlfrescoConnector</class>
        <userHeader>X-Alfresco-Remote-User</userHeader>
     </connector>
```

Of course, change the header name to what you are using.
Then, use it in the alfresco endpoint:

```
     <endpoint>
        <id>alfresco</id>
        <name>Alfresco - user access</name>
        <description>Access to Alfresco Repository WebScripts that require user authentication</description>
        <connector-id>alfrescoHeader</connector-id>
        <endpoint-url>http://localhost:8080/alfresco/wcs</endpoint-url>
        <identity>user</identity>
        <external-auth>true</external-auth>
     </endpoint>
```